# java exec attempting to untar a file

Tags: java, tar, runtime.exec

I have been trying to untar a .tbz file without a lot of success in a java app. I have now decided to try and hit the command line to get the job done, and it currently doesn't through any errors but it doesn't untar the file, either. Can anyone see an issue with this?

```
    String[] cmd = { "tar", "-xjf", "/var/tmp/filename.tbz"};

    Process p =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, null);
```

EDIT, this works:

```
    List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
    commands.add("tar");
    commands.add("-xvjf");
    commands.add("/var/tmp/filename.tbz");

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
    Process p = pb.start();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            p.getInputStream()));
    String readline;
    while ((readline = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(readline);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a `cd` command doing there in the middle? Perhaps you meant this:

```
String[] cmd = { "tar", "-xjf", "/var/tmp/filename.tbz"};
```

If instead of the above, you really want to do this:

```
cd /var/tmp
tar -xjf filename.tbz
```

In this case you can use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory).

Comment: i changed it and still no error and no output, i am looking at processbuilder, is the first portion requiring "tar" and the rest the string?

Comment: This does not produce any output. To read the output you would need a bit more work. But the code I gave you should extract the file.

Comment: To get the output, see this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/

Comment: I'm doing this:                                                                                      List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
            commands.add("tar");
            commands.add("-xvjf");
            commands.add("/var/tmp/filename.tbz"); 

            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);                          and still no extraction. this is so frustrating.